# Windows 10 wakeup after sleep takes more than a minute

Tags: windows-10, wake-up

I have Windows 10 home 64 with auto update on. I recently have been having delay in wake-up after sleep with black screen for more than a minute. I never had this problem before and I have not installed any third party software just before this problem occurred. Once logged in the speed looks normal.

Answer (score 1):

Check your current build to make sure it's updated to latest build Windows 10 1703(build 15063.540), then update all available devices driver to the latest, include BIOS.
If it doesn't work, perform a In-Place Upgrade repair using Windows 10 installation media.

Comment: Thanks Karen. My Laptop has the latest build. I do not have the media as I upgraded from Win 7 to 10. Win 7 came loaded in my Laptop. Please let me know how to update BIOS.

Comment: It depends on the model of your computer. You need to visit its manufacture's website to download the latest version of BIOS to update.